# c++ A* in grid game

Tags: c++, algorithm, game-engine, game-physics

I have grid for game ( cells are enumerated in pairs of integer like in matrix). Every cell has different cost of crossing ( from 0 to 1000000 ). Can anyone suggest me A* implementation ( different than micropather) for finding path ?  My bots can step in small increment, not just to jump on next cell.

Comment: If your movement is not cell oriented pure A* alone is probably not going to be good enough for your needs. You'll need some kind of path straightening/smoothing algorithm too.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to use instead is [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). A* can in fact be considered as just a generalisation of Dijkstra's.

Comment: A* is always faster than Dijkstra's Algorithm, if a reasonable heuristic is used. There is no reason to use Dijkstras where A* is possible. He is looking for an implementation, not an algorithm, as well.

Comment: @DeadMG: Well, that's not [entirely true](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11606823/238419)..