# Regarding the query speed of dijkstra and A* algorithm

Tags: shortest-path, dijkstra

I am trying to profile the speed of A* and Dijkstra algorithm. I am using the code available at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/example/astar-cities.cpp and http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html. I tried a simple graph with 500 edges and 300 nodes.

I was expecting A* to perform better than Dijkstra since in Dijkstra the shortest distance from the source vertex to every other vertex is found. On the other hand in A* the shortest distance to the goal node is only found.

However, profiling showed that Dijkstra performed slightly better than A*. Is it possible or I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Djikstra's algorithm uses a queue while A* uses a priority queue.  In general, queues will perform better than priority queues *(eg. enqueue/dequeue from a queue using a linked-list or circular-array is `O(1)`, while enqueue/dequeue from a priority queue using a heap is `O(log n)`)*.

However, again in general, the cases where this small difference causes A* to run slower than Djikstra's tend to be the cases where both algorithms run extremely fast anyways - in small mazes, and mazes with only a small number of paths to consider *(such as a zig-zagging maze)*.  In the slower cases *(out in the open with few obstacles)*, A
* should run much faster.

Since your case has 300-nodes, there's a good chance there's something wrong with your code.  Without seeing it, we can't help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either your **heuristic** is inaccurate, or your A* is performing **more passes** over the data set than Dijkstra (again, perhaps due to the heuristic).

EDIT: For example, if your A* implementation traverses the whole data set and only expands a single node each time (the one with the best heuristic), then it could perform *more* passes overall than Dijkstra (which expands each node as soon as possible).

If possible, profile the number of *passes* being performed by each algorithm rather than only looking at the overall processing time.

Comment: I have simply used the euclidean distance as the heuristic

Comment: @user31820: That should be fine as a heuristic. Check the number of passes - see edit.